# Can't verify Go generated ECDSA signature with JS

Tags: javascript, flutter, go, cryptography, ecdsa

I've got a small issue, (My assumption is that there is one small thing holding me back but I have no clue what), as mentioned in the title.

I will start by giving an overview about what I'm doing and will provide everything I have afterwards.

### Project overview

I'm hashing files with `SHA-256` in a mobile app and sign the hash in the backend with an `ECDSA P-256` key. This is then persisted. If the user needs to he can verify the integretify of the file, by basically hashing the file again and looking up the hash and getting the hash, some metadata and the signature back.

To validate the data has been submitted my app and not a third party (the hashs are persisted in a blockchain but that doesn't really matter for this issue), the app will attempt to verify the signature with the public key. This **works** fine.

Now I would like to add this option to my website as well, however here is the issue. My signatures are not valid if I use the `jsrsasign` or the`webcrypto` api.

### Data

- Sample signature: `3045022100f28c29042a6d766810e21f2c0a1839f93140989299cae1d37b49a454373659c802203d0967be0696686414fe2efed3a71bc1639d066ee127cfb7c0ad369521459d00`
- Public Key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEq6iOuQeIhlhywCjo5yoABGODOJRZ
c6/L8XzUYEsocCbc/JHiByGjuB3G9cSU2vUi1HUy5LsCtX2wlHSEObGVBw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

- Hash: `bb5dbfcb5206282627254ab23397cda842b082696466f2563503f79a5dccf942`

### Scripts

JS Code

```js
const validHash = document.getElementById("valid-hash");
const locationEmbedded = document.getElementById("location-embedded")
const signatureValid = document.getElementById("valid-sig")
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-upload');
const mcaptchaToken = document.getElementById("mcaptcha__token")
const submission = document.getElementById("submission")
let publicKey;

fileSelector.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("file-upload-label")[0].innerHTML = event.target.files[0].name
})
submission.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
    let token = mcaptchaToken.value
    if (token == null || token == "") {
        alert("Please activate the Captcha!")
        return
    }
    const fileList = fileSelector.files;
    if (fileList[0]) {
        const file = fileList[0]
        const fileSize = file.size;
        let fileData = await readBinaryFile(file)
        let byteArray = new Uint8Array(fileData);
        const bytes = await hashFile(byteArray)
        try {
            let resp = await callApi(toHex(bytes), token)
            validHash.innerHTML = "\u2713"

            const mediainfo = await MediaInfo({ format: 'object' }, async (mediaInfo) => { // Taken from docs
                mediaInfo.analyzeData(() => file.size, (chunkSize, offset) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        const reader = new FileReader()
                        reader.onload = (event) => {
                            if (event.target.error) {
                                reject(event.target.error)
                            }
                            resolve(new Uint8Array(event.target.result))
                        }
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize))
                    })
                })
                try {
                    let tags = mediaInfo.media.track[0].extra
                    latitude = tags.LATITUDE
                    longitude = tags.LONGITUDE
                    if (latitude && longitude) {
                        locationEmbedded.innerHTML = "\u2713"
                    } else {
                        locationEmbedded.innerHTML = "\u2717"
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    locationEmbedded.innerHTML = "\u2717"
                }
               
            })
            if (publicKey == undefined) {
                let req = await fetch("/publickey")
                if (req.ok) {
                    publicKey = await req.text()
                } else {
                    throw "Could not get public key"
                }
            }

            let signature = resp.data.comment
            if (signature == null || signature == "") {
                throw "No signature found"
            }
            //const timeStamps = resp.data.timestamps
            const hashString = resp.data.hash_string
            console.log(hashString)
            if (hashString !== toHex(bytes)) {
                validHash.innerHTML = "\u2717"
            } else {
                validHash.innerHTML = "\u2713"
            }
            const result = await validateSignature(publicKey, signature, hashString)
            console.log("Valid signature: " + result)
            if (result) {
                signatureValid.innerHTML = "\u2713"
            } else {
                signatureValid.innerHTML = "\u2717"
            }
            mcaptchaToken.value = ""
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Error: " + e)
            window.location.reload()
        }

    } else {
        alert("No file selected");
    }
});


function toHex(buffer) {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(buffer, x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

async function callApi(hash, token) {
    const url = "/verify";
    let resp = await fetch(url, {
        headers: { "X-MCAPTCHA-TOKEN": token },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ hash: hash })
    })
    if (resp.ok) {
        return await resp.json();
    } else {
        if (resp.status == 401) {
            throw resp.status
        } else {
            console.log(resp)
            throw "Your hash is either invalid or has not been submitted via the Decentproof App!"
        }
    }
}

async function hashFile(byteArray) {
    let hashBytes = await window.crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', byteArray);
    return new Uint8Array(hashBytes)
}

async function validateSignature(key, signature,hashData) {
    const importedKey = importPublicKey(key)
    const sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({"alg": "SHA256withECDSA"});
    sig.init(importedKey)
    sig.updateHex(hashData);
    return sig.verify(signature)
}

function readBinaryFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = () => {
            resolve(fr.result)
        };
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
}

function importPublicKey(pem) {
    console.log(pem)
    return KEYUTIL.getKey(pem); 
  }

  function hexToBytes(hex) {
    for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
    return new Uint8Array(bytes);
}
```

App Verification Code (Flutter Dart)

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'package:decentproof/features/verification/interfaces/ISignatureVerifcationService.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asn1/asn1_parser.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/asn1/primitives/asn1_integer.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/signers/ecdsa_signer.dart';

class SignatureVerificationService implements ISignatureVerificationService {
  late final ECPublicKey pubKey;
  SignatureVerificationService() {
    pubKey = loadAndPrepPubKey();
  }

  final String pemPubKey = """
-----BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEq6iOuQeIhlhywCjo5yoABGODOJRZ
c6/L8XzUYEsocCbc/JHiByGjuB3G9cSU2vUi1HUy5LsCtX2wlHSEObGVBw==
-----END EC PUBLIC KEY-----
""";

  ECSignature loadAndConvertSignature(String sig) {
    //Based on: https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/issues/159#issuecomment-1105689978
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(hex.decode(sig));
    ASN1Parser p = ASN1Parser(bytes);
    //Needs to be dynamic or otherwise throws odd errors
    final seq = p.nextObject() as dynamic;
    ASN1Integer ar = seq.elements?[0] as ASN1Integer;
    ASN1Integer as = seq.elements?[1] as ASN1Integer;
    BigInt r = ar.integer!;
    BigInt s = as.integer!;
    return ECSignature(r, s);
  }

  ECPublicKey loadAndPrepPubKey() {
    return CryptoUtils.ecPublicKeyFromPem(pemPubKey);
  }

  @override
  bool verify(String hash, String sig) {
    ECSignature convertedSig = loadAndConvertSignature(sig);
    final ECDSASigner signer = ECDSASigner();
    signer.init(false, PublicKeyParameter<ECPublicKey>(loadAndPrepPubKey()));
    Uint8List messageAsBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(hash));
    return signer.verifySignature(messageAsBytes, convertedSig);
  }
}
```

Key generation script (Go)

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var outPutDir string
    var outPutFileName string
    flag.StringVar(&outPutDir, "out", "./", "Output directory")
    flag.StringVar(&outPutFileName, "name", "key", "Output file name e.g key, my_project_key etc. Adding .pem is not needed")
    flag.Parse()
    key, err := generateKeys()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Something went wrong %d", err)
        return
    }
    err = saveKeys(key, outPutDir, outPutFileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Something went wrong %d", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Keys generated and saved to %s%s.pem and %spub_%s.pem", outPutDir, outPutFileName, outPutDir, outPutFileName)

}

func generateKeys() (*ecdsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    return ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
}
func saveKeys(key *ecdsa.PrivateKey, outPutDir string, outPutFileName string) error {
    bytes, err := x509.MarshalECPrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    privBloc := pem.Block{Type: "EC PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: bytes}
    privKeyFile, err := os.Create(outPutDir + outPutFileName + ".pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer privKeyFile.Close()
    err = pem.Encode(privKeyFile, &privBloc)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    bytes, err = x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(&key.PublicKey)
    pubBloc := pem.Block{Type: "EC Public KEY", Bytes: bytes}
    pubKeyFile, err := os.Create(outPutDir + "pub_" + outPutFileName + ".pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer pubKeyFile.Close()
    err = pem.Encode(pubKeyFile, &pubBloc)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Link to signature wrapper script: [Link](https://github.com/Flajt/decentproof-backend/blob/main/sign/signature_manger.go)

### My Attemps

- I've tested with two new key pairs (and your lib) to sign some sample data to see if the something with the keys is wrong, it's not
- I've tested signing data with your lib and my private key and validating it with my public key to see if my private key is broken, it's not
- I've attempted the whole thing with the web crypto api, it didn't work
- I've attempted to load the `ECDSA` public key and use `new KJUR.crypto.ECDSA({"curve":"secp256r1"}).verifyHex(hash, signature,pubKeyHex)` with the data mentioned above, it didn't work (tested only in the browser console)
- I've used a Firefox and Safari to see if there is any difference, it didn't change anything
- I've tried passing my hash as string via `sig.updateString(hashData)`, it didn't work
- And some other smaller change stuff
- Compare hash, r & s + signature on web and app site, everything matches as it should.
- I've traced the whole thing from front to backend and there are no data changes

My last attempt was the 4th attempt, since, from my understanding at least, if you are using the regular way (which I'm doing in the script above) your data get's hashed, which, in my case, is counter productive as I've already gotten a hash so if it's hashed twice it ,of course, won't match. However for reasons I don't get I still get false as return value.

One final thought, could the issue be that the go ecdsa libary truncates the message down to 32 bytes if the `P-256` signature is used? And maybe in JS it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verification in the JavaScript code is incompatible with the Dart code for two reasons:

- Firstly, the JavaScript code uses [`KJUR.crypto.Signature()`](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.Signature.html), which hashes the data *implicitly*. Since the data is already hashed, this results in double hashing. On the Dart side, no implicit hashing occurs (since no digest is specified in [`ECDSASigner()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pointycastle/latest/impl.signer.ecdsa_signer/ECDSASigner/ECDSASigner.html)).
  To avoid implicit hashing on the JavaScript side and to be compatible with the Dart code, [`KJUR.crypto.ECDSA()`](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.ECDSA.html) can be used instead of `KJUR.crypto.Signature()`.
- Secondly, `updateHex()` in the JavaScript code performs a hex decoding of the hex encoded hash, while in the Dart code the hex encoded hash is UTF-8 encoded.
  To be compatible with the Dart code, the hex encoded hash must also be UTF-8 encoded in the JavaScript code.

The following JavaScript code fixes both issues:

```js
(async () => {

var spki = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEq6iOuQeIhlhywCjo5yoABGODOJRZ
c6/L8XzUYEsocCbc/JHiByGjuB3G9cSU2vUi1HUy5LsCtX2wlHSEObGVBw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`; 
var pubkey = KEYUTIL.getKey(spki).getPublicKeyXYHex()
var pubkeyHex = '04' + pubkey.x + pubkey.y

var msgHashHex = ArrayBuffertohex(new TextEncoder().encode("bb5dbfcb5206282627254ab23397cda842b082696466f2563503f79a5dccf942").buffer)
// var msgHashHex = ArrayBuffertohex(new TextEncoder().encode("bb5dbfcb5206282627254ab23397cda8").buffer); // works also since only the first 32 bytes are considered for P-256

var sigHex = "3045022100f28c29042a6d766810e21f2c0a1839f93140989299cae1d37b49a454373659c802203d0967be0696686414fe2efed3a71bc1639d066ee127cfb7c0ad369521459d00"

var ec = new KJUR.crypto.ECDSA({'curve': 'secp256r1'})
var verified = ec.verifyHex(msgHashHex, sigHex, pubkeyHex)
console.log("Verification:", verified)
 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/10.4.0/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>
```

Now, verification is successful.

---

Note regarding the UTF-8 encoding of the hex encoded hash: This produces 64 bytes, so that ECDSA with P-256 only considers the first 32 bytes of the data, i.e. the last 32 bytes are ignored (for more details see [FIPS 186-5](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf), section 6.4, last paragraph).
Actually this is either a bug or a bad design in the signing code. More correct would be a hex decoding, which would provide 32 bytes so that the entire data would be taken into account.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work out, the bad design part is on me xd (the utf-8 encoding). I just realized it yesterday after posting, but it was to late to get a coherent thought together. 
I'm now adjusting everything to decode the hex part as it seems to be the most propper way to do things.